# Clash of clans account lost

Tags: clash-of-clans

When I was playing my phone was hanging and I refreshed all the apps by mistake (including CoC). My account was not paired with google play.

Is there any way to retrieve my CoC account?

Answer (score 6):

As you didn't pair your account, there is no way to recover your village.